# Socket.io chat through apache server (also running php main site)

Tags: apache, node.js, socket.io, cors

I have been trying to come up with a solution for my website to play nicely with socket.io. Right now I have apache serving my website (mostly in php) and I am trying to implement a live chat support feature using socket.io (node). I am able to get the chat functionality working separately (using express and going to wundertutor.com:8000) but when I just go to wundertutor.com (where the chat functionality is included as well), I am getting issues with CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). Here is my error (on the client side):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://chat.wundertutor.com/socket.io/1/?t=1356421805823. Origin http://wundertutor.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

OR

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://chat.wundertutor.com/socket.io/1/?t=1356422229000. Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

depending on wether I include this line of code in my app.js

```
io.set("origins","http://wundertutor.com");
```

Basically, I just want my node app to be a suppliment to my main site, but I really don't know where to specify the CORS parameters. I have tried doing this in my .htaccess file, in app.js, as well as in the client javascript, none of which have proved successful.

(Also, another thing I find strange is that when I go to wundertutor.com:8000, my node app correctly opens up a websocket, but when I try to go to wundertutor.com, it tries to use XHR polling which ends up causing this CORS mess)

Any suggestions would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my problem if anyone else is experiencing the same issue. While I still think that what I am trying to do is using CORS, I didn't have to do any specific setting of Access-Allow-Origin-Control on either the Apache or node.js side. What I did to fix my problem was to serve the socket.io javascript file from the node.js server as opposed to the apache server. This made the requests coming from the socket.io javascript file have the same origin as where the javascript file was loaded. Here is an example:

```
<script src="http://wundertutor.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script> 
(node server - correct)
```

vs

```
<script src="/javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
(apache server - wrong)
```

Comment: This does not explain how exactly you got Apache to work with nodeJS together.